# Sorting a dynamically allocated, multidimensional C array with std::sort and lambda function in C++11

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, c++11, lambda

I'm trying to sort a 2D, dynamically allocated array using `std::sort` with a custom sorting function using lambda. `numFaces` is an integer value determined at the start of the program and doesn't change during the program's lifespan. Here's my current approach.

```
float(*data)[24] = new float[numFaces][24];
std::sort(data, data + numFaces,  [](float (&A)[24], float (&B)[24]) -> bool
{
    return comparison(A, B); // Pseudo
});
```

The program is failing to compile with this error:

> array type 'float [24]' is not assignable

Since I've specified in the lambda declaration that the parameters should be references I can't see why the compiler is producing this error message. I am using the VC++ compiler from Microsoft's Visual Studio Community Edition 2015.
[Here's a quick pastebin of the entire log](http://pastebin.com/WSLQftXY)

Line 38 is the closing bracket of the lambda function declaration.

I know I could solve this in a couple different ways, but if there is a way to make this work, I would prefer to continue like this. If you have a suggestion to another solution that lets the data be stored contiguously and sorted in these groups of 28 floats I would be delighted to hear about that too.

Ways I could solve the current issue which would introduce other issues and/or bigger delay in the application:

- Using `qsort` with void pointers, casting them and sorting pretty much the same way. I'm a bit unsure whether or not this would introduce any more delay when the `std::sort` doesn't have all the information about the container that it would have if I was using `std::vector`s.
- Using `std::sort` with nested `std::vector`s. The data wouldn't always be stored contiguously on memory, which would in turn force me to create copies of the data every time the vector is sorted. I tested this and checked the locations on memory with the VS debugger, but again I am not 100% sure this can't be solved somehow.
- Using `std::vector` of a custom class/struct with the needed data. If there is no simple solution to my problem I will do this or do the sorting without any STL calls.

Tiny notice: The code in the code tag above has been stripped of unnecessary code. The pastebin is a bit different because of this.

---

**A quick recap of the problem with a solution:**

`std::sort` rearranges the elements of whatever you are sorting by **assigning one element to another**. Because of this the elements have to be **assignable**, which C-style arrays simply aren't. There are a number of ways to go about solving this, but if you need the data to be stored **contiguously** on memory you need a type holding exactly the data the array would be holding; no more, no less. `std::array` is the perfect type for this as people have pointed out in the comments. Here's an example solution:

```
#include <vector>
#include <array>

std::vector<std::array<float, 24>> data;
```

And with the following `std::sort` call:

```
std::sort(data.begin(), data.end(), [](const std::array<float, 24> &A, const std::array<float, 24> &B) -> bool
{
    return A[0] < B[0]; // Sample sort condition
});
```

Comment: +1 for coming up with a working solution. -1 for only partially re-implementing `std::array` :)  (seriously, check out `std::array`, it's a more generic and complete implementation compared to the above struct)

Comment: Extending the `std::array` and overriding the assign operator is probably a better way to go, but unnecessary for my current needs, and I'm not a 100% sure it would keep all the data packed on memory.

Comment: Here's a quick GIF of the sorting taking place. It's working quite nicely.
[imgur.com/iPNSBmJ](http://imgur.com/iPNSBmJ)

Comment: I like your implementation (especially since you produced something that solved the root cause of your issue), but `faceData` is literally a subset of `std::array`. _An instance of array<T, N> stores N elements of type T... The elements of an array are stored contiguously... Class array relies on the implicitly-declared special member functions (12.1, 12.4, and 12.8) to conform to the container requirements table in 23.2._. Table 96 requires that the containers (of which `std::array<>` is one) are assignable from an lvalue. What about `std::array` didn't work for your application?

Comment: All I can remember was it had some weird error messages. "Unknown size" when it was defined as array<float, 24>. I bet I could make it work somehow though.
Even though data is stored contiguously in the `std::array` itself, are you sure it doesn't have any more data than that? If it does have anything but the array, the data will no longer be packed in the outer vector and will no longer be readable by incrementing a pointer to the first float in the vector. I'm using this for convenience when loading the floats to a buffer in OpenGL.

Comment: [yes, I'm sure there are no objects in `std::array` other than the data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If you got an error, then you made some mistake. Its interface is a superset of `faceData`'s.

Comment: @mkal Thanks for all the help. I can't remember why it wouldn't work out using `std::array` earlier, but it worked just fine when I wrote it out this time. I've updated the example solution to use `std::array` and it's running at the exact same speed with all the added benefits the `std::array` class brings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, the basics:

```
float(*data)[24] = new float[numFaces][24];
```

Here you define `data` as dynamic array of size `numFaces`, each element of it is an array of static size `24`, which means `data[0]` is an array of size `24`, `data[1]` is an array of size `24` and so on.

So sorting `data` using `std::sort` means sorting the elements — `data[0]`, `data[1]`, `data[2]`, `...`, `data[numFaces-1]` —  which are *statically-sized* arrays themselves.

> > Since I've specified in the lambda declaration that the parameters should be      references I can't see why the compiler is producing this error message.

The error is because arrays are not assignable in C++ (and C as well), as the error message says it clearly. In order to sort the elements, the `std::sort` needs to rearrange the elements, and that is done by assignment only — there is no other approach used by the library. It uses iterators and somewhere does this:

```
 *it1 =  *it2;   //it1 and it2 point to arrays
```

which is basically equivalent to this,

```
data[i1] = data[i2];
```

Since `data[i1]` is an array (of *static* size `24`), the above assignment is invalid. You'll get the same error if you do this:

```
float a[24], b[24];

a = b; //error
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh. The error message now makes a lot more sense than it did earlier. Thanks a bunch. I tried to solve this earlier with a 1D array, but couldn't figure out a way of not sorting by every individual float. Is there any approach you would recommend to this problem?

Comment: @Whitehooder, Objects of `std::array<float, 24>` are assignable, unlike "normal" arrays.  Would dynamic arrays of those meet your requirements? The syntax may be easier to understand as well... `using Face = std::array<float, 24>;`

Comment: @mkal, I did try that, but it seemed to have some of the same problems and restrictions. I ended up creating a struct holding an array of 24 floats and overloaded the assign operator with a basic loop setting all the values of the array the way I initially thought STL did it. It's working nicely now and I've moved on to refining the sorting function. Thanks for all the advice.

Comment: @Whitehooder as others have said, the fact that the `std::array` solution isn't working just means you made a different mistake, not that `std::array` was the mistake.

Comment: @Yakk, I understand. I'll have another look at it eventually and will update the post with a better solution when I do.